# Tkinter image not showing or giving an error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have tried two different things to try to get an image to show in a label

```
#This gives " TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "TestImage.gif" "
imgPath = "TestImage.gif"
photo = PhotoImage(file = imgPath)
label = Label(image = photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

and

```
#This gives no error but the image doesn't show
imgPath = "TestImage.gif"
photo = PhotoImage(imgPath)
label = Label(image = photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

The image is in the same folder as all the code. Any suggestions on how to show an image?

Comment: The first seems to be giving you useful information. Are you certain the image is a proper .gif?

Comment: It was a jpeg that I saved as a .gif (Type says GIF File). So I'm assuming that's alright.

Comment: no, that's not alright. Tkinter only supports files in the GIF format, no matter what the name is. Simply changing the name doesn't automatically make it a GIF. To display jpeg you'll need to use PIL.

Comment: So even though it's file type is .gif and it only opens in browsers, it's still not a gif?

Comment: Correct. The filename is unimportant. Browsers have support for many file types that Tkinter does not.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8nHaRCL.png
This is the image I am trying to use. Not the imgur picture but the .gif in the folder screenshot. TestImage.

Answer (score 7):

Bryan Oakley is correct, the image is not a jpg in terms of its content, even though your filesystem thinks it's a gif.

On my end I tried opening a jpg with your program and got the same error 'TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "hello.jpg".'

So you can do this: Open your image with mspaint, then go to File > Save As and from the "Save As Type" dropdown, choose GIF. Then the code should work. This is what I used:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

imgPath = r"hello.gif"
photo = PhotoImage(file = imgPath)
label = Label(image = photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

(btw, if I changed line 7 above to `photo = PhotoImage(imgPath)` then like you, no image appears. So leave it as `photo = PhotoImage(file = imgPath)`)