# Tkinter: Image not recognised

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple GUI program I'm building with Tkinter. I want to have a bunch of buttons with app images on them that, when clicked, launch that app. The problem is, Python can't recognise the `Skype.gif` file.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def open_skype():
    os.system('open /Applications/Skype.app')

master = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file='/Users/michael/Desktop/Skype.gif')

but = Button(master, image=photo, command=open_skype)



objs = [but]

column = 1
for i in objs:
    i.grid(column=column, row=1)
    column += 1
mainloop()
```

Error message:

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "/Users/michael/Desktop/Skype.gif"

Comment: Use image in `PNG` or `JPG` format.

Comment: I tried those and I got the same error: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "/Users/michael/Desktop/Skype.png"

Comment: How did you convert it from `GIF` to `PNG` ? Can you see this image  in some image viewer ?

Comment: Definitely converted it, and it isn't corrupt.

Comment: Can you see this image in some image viewer ?

Comment: Yeah, preview on mac.

Comment: Probably you will need install and import another module for images - see [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) in [Tkinterbook](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)

Comment: have you checked this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718663/tkinter-image-not-showing-or-giving-an-error

Comment: Try with this image http://furas.pl/screenshot.gif  It works for me. If it doesn't work for you maybe you need some library in system or module in python.

Comment: You can try in console/terminal `file Skype.gif` - maybe it give you some inforamtion about file format.

Comment: Yeah, that image doesn't work, and in terminal it replies: Skype.gif: data

Comment: Not directly connected to the problem but `objs` and the loop look very strange and unnecessarily complex.  `but.grid(column=1, row=1)` has the same effect.  BTW counting of rows and columns starts at 0.  You are leaving cells in that grid unused.

Comment: `file screenshot.gif` gives me `screenshot.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 809 x 775` so `file Skype.gif` should give you something similar.

Comment: @BlackJack, I'm planning to do this with lots of buttons and I just wrote that out so I could add to the array as I wanted. Also, the way I did it nicely keeps each widget on the same row, and lays them out as they are in the array. Column is for future use. Furas, it only replies Skype.gif: data. I'm on a mac if that helps.

Comment: Did you try `file screenshot.gif` ? Well, maybe you will have to install `PIL` to work with other image formats - see `Tkinterbook` again.

Comment: The way you did it every widget in `objs` would go into the very same cell. Maybe you meant to write `for i, wigdet in enumerate(objs):` and use `i` as value for `column`, the point is that's half baked code irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Ah, I didn't paste column += 1

Comment: `enumerate(objs)` or `enumerate(objs,1)` is good idea :) better then `column += 1`

Comment: Nah, it's fine - my code works. I see why it's better though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that the image is not in the correct place. TO ensure that it is, try entering your command line (Terminal for Macs), and typing in `ls /Users/michael/Desktop/Skype.gif`. If prints `Skype.gif` or `/Users/michael/Desktop/Skype.gif`, then the file is there, otherwise it is not.

Comment: No, that's not the problem - I made sure the path's right.

Answer (score 0):

The path starts at where the python file is located so if they're in the same folder just put `photo = PhotoImage(file='Skype.gif')`

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter only recognize s PNG images or JPG images in some cases. If you have a gif image you can incorporate it by using another module called WxPython. How this works is that it uses Frame by frame images to display a video type image. Tkinter does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image is in the format of PNG or JPG